# Whenever I try to ping some website URL, the IP address it finds is always 127.0.0.1 (loopback IP)

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, ping, url

Whenever I try to ping some website URL, the IP address it finds is always 127.0.0.1 (loopback IP)

There are many websites where this happens such as `mega.co.nz`, `1337x.to` and many more.

[image]

I have checked my hosts file, the URLs are not blacklisted in the hosts file.

How can I get ping to show the real IP address?

Google Chrome or FireFox just shows website unavailable

As I can access every other site on internet, so I know I am connected to internet. I also have scanned my system for viruses, and zero viruses were detected.

I am already using Google DNS servers on my router. I tried NS Lookup for which I have attached the results:

[image]

Now when I try to ping the given ip address, it pings successfully. But when I try to open the webpage using the same IP address in Google Chrome, it gives error:

> "Connection Refused"

I also tried to ping it using IPv6 option, but the result was: "request timeout"

As my ISP does not support IPv6.

Comment: Are you connected to the a network or the Internet properly? Have you ran virus and malware scans to ensure the PC is clean?

Comment: As i can access every other site on internet, so i know i am connected to internet. I also have scanned my system for virus,  zero detection.

Comment: Use `nslookup`, try different DNS servers (like Google DNS, if you’re comfortable with that).

Comment: i am already using Google DNS Servers on my Router. I tried NSLooKup for which i have attached the results

Comment: I hope you have checked `hosts` file. `127.0.0.1` is the `localhost` and yous `hosts` file might be pointing the URL of interest to `localhost`

Comment: Yes i have checked it.
As i have mentioned it in the post also.

Comment: please do `ipconfig /flushdns` and try again

Comment: i have already done it.

Comment: Ping with the -6 option for IPv6 to see if IPv6 answer (localhost is ::1)

Comment: I tried it, but result was request timed out.

Comment: still i cannot find a answer, can someone please help me ?

Comment: Have you tried a `tracert` to see where the packets go?

Comment: Yes i did, it just replied back from my local web address

Answer (score 0):

Use nslookup with a server specified on the command line. Verify that the server is correct and then double-check the results with a server online. You may want to use a server that is known for not censoring the results.

Example on a Mac:

```
nslookup www.google.com 89.233.43.71
```

I don't have access to a Windows box, but the Microsoft online help says specifying the server is an option.

Answer (score 0):

> Now When i try to ping the given ip address, it pings successfully. But when i try to open the webpage using the same ip address in Google chrome, it gives error : "Connection Refused"

A firewall (either on your pc or on your ISP's side) is blocking tcp connections, but not icmp traffic.

About the ping resolving to 127.0.0.1, it could be because Netbios resolve is set to a higher priority than DNS and something is answering that query. You probably have a piece of software on your computer that was designed to block connections to these websites.

Check your netbios table using `nbtstat -n`

Answer (score 0):

kaared's post was helpful in my case.

Let me explain: I set my DNS as 1.1.1.3 (Cloudfare family plan).

`nslookup 1337x.to 1.1.1.3` gives the following output:

```
Server:     1.1.1.3
Address:    1.1.1.3#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   1337x.to
Address: 0.0.0.0
Name:   1337x.to
Address: ::
```

While `nslookup 1337x.to 1.1.1.1` gives the following output:

```
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   1337x.to
Address: 104.31.16.118
Name:   1337x.to
Address: 104.31.16.11
```

which leads the ping test to this output:

```
PING 1337x.to (104.31.16.118) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 104.31.16.118 (104.31.16.118): icmp_seq=1 ttl=249 time=18.1 ms
64 bytes from 104.31.16.118 (104.31.16.118): icmp_seq=2 ttl=249 time=18.5 ms

--- 1337x.to ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.132/18.329/18.527/0.197 ms
```

The reason why the domain is routed to a black hole in the first case is to prevent Malware and Adult Content (it could be for legal purposes for others).

To conclude, it is solved by changing the DNS servers.